# Cygwin X on high DPI

Tags: cygwin, dpi, high-dpi, cygwin-x

On my Windows 10 Surface Pro (2736x1824 resolution), whenever I connect via PuTTY to an Ubuntu 14.04 server and run Eclipse or gVim over Cygwin X, the text and windows are extremely small.

I can drag the windows over to my desktop monitor (1920x1080), but that just takes the image at the size it would be on the 2736x1824 screen and scales it down to be the same approximate size (only fuzzier, due to the lower resolution).

Is there any way to get Cygwin or the Unix X programs I'm running to recognize the DPI, or automatically scale images, or similar?

I saw that Cygwin's X has a [DPI option](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/Xserver.1.html), but I can't tell that it has any effect on gVim or Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands in the server's `bash` session before running apps:

```
export GDK_SCALE=2
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2
export ELM_SCALE=2
```

You can add those lines to `~/.bash_profile` to make that automatic on future logins.

Source: [HiDPI - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GUI_toolkits)

Comment: It looks like this doesn't help gVim, but it does help Eclipse (as long as Eclipse is using its default GTK3 support). Thanks for the tips and the link.

Comment: Have you tried the GTK3 version of gVim? https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim-gtk3

Answer (score 0):

Install MATE and the desktop mode and it should be working.

For multiwindow mode, run mate-terminal or mintty terminal from the xwin-xdg-menu (green tray icon) and type:

```
/usr/libexec/mate-settings-daemon.exe &
```

to make all gtk processes respect scaling